# Подключение статичных файлом по одному

Tags: веб-программирование, golang, app

Я знаю, что можно подключить статичные файлы таким образом `viewRouter.PathPrefix("/assets/).Handler(http.StripPrefix("/assets/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./assets/"))))`, но так подключается вся папка сразу и любой пользователь может перемещаться по ней.

Хотел сделать так чтобы доступ открывался для каждого файла по отдельности, но без доступа к папке таким же образом, но получаю 404.

Также хотел сделать так, чтобы можно было создавать файл и давать доступ только с одного компьютера по ip, но не смог нагуглить как это сделать. Подскажите что курить для решения этого вопроса)

Answer (score 1):

Имплементируйте интерфейс `http.FileSystem` с помощью обёртки над `http.Dir`:

```
type WhiteListDir struct {
    http.Dir
    WhiteList map[string]bool
}

func (d WhiteListDir) Open(name string) (http.File, error) {
    if d.WhiteList[name] {
        return d.Dir.Open(name)
    }

    return nil, os.ErrPermission
}
```

Использование:

```
dir := WhiteListDir{
    Dir: http.Dir("./assets/"),
    WhiteList: map[string]bool{
        "/robots.txt": true,
    },
}
viewRouter.PathPrefix("/assets/).Handler(
    http.StripPrefix("/assets/", http.FileServer(dir)),
)
```

Такая имплементация будет выдавать 403 на всё, кроме `robots.txt`. Поддержка директорий — упражнение со звёздочкой.